# expect script to automate telnet login

Tags: telnet, expect

I have been trying to create an expect script to automatically login to my device through telnet

If there are no multiple possibilities for the expect command , the script works fine, logs in to the device.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]

spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'." sleep .1;
send "\r";
sleep .1;
expect   "login:"
send "$user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

The script above works fine and logs in successfully when i pass the correct parameters. But once i add additional branches(for error handling) to the expect command , the script gets stuck at `login:` prompt.After some time it prints [Script Error](http://pastebin.com/n6CX8mtv)
Any help?? Erroneous script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]

spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'."
sleep .1;
send "\r";
expect
{
  "login:"
  {
        send "$user\r"
        expect "Password:"
        send "$password\r";
        interact

  }

  "host: Connection refused"
  {
    send_user "ERROR:EXITING!"
    exit
  }

}
```

PS: This script is to be further developed to wait for additional prompts to load different build images on the device. Only telnet(console) connection works. so ssh is not an option.

Comment: Care to share how you accomplished passing additional commands once logged in? I'm not able to get past that hurdle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148832/shell-script-successful-telnet-login-how-to-issue-commands-after-that

Comment: if you are talking about executing additional commands in the shell automatically through the script. you are supposed to use send command . interact passes the ball to the user . From the question u posted i see that you have already got an answer. :) expect for the win..

Comment: what is the "send" command @woodstok ?  I'm not seeing how that connects up with telnet automation.  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/send

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bad. 
The problem was with the curly braces. They are supposed to be at the same line as the expect command .

Answer (score 0):

here is a script using `expect` to achieve telnet auto login. I just tried and it really works.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
if {[llength $argv] < 1} {
    puts "Usage: ./telnet.sh host";
    exit 1;
}
set timeout 10
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user "my_user"
set password "my_password"
spawn telnet -l $user $host
expect {
    "?ser*" {
        send "$user\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "?ogin*" {
        send "$user\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "?assword*" {
        send "$password\n"
        interact
        exit 0;
    }
}
exit 1
```

link: https://www.oueta.com/linux/telnet-auto-login-on-linux-and-unix-with-expect/