# Shell script successful telnet login, how to issue commands after that?

Tags: shell, telnet, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 10.21.0.17
expect -re "login"
send "admin\n"
expect -re "Password"
send "supersecurepassword\n"
interact
```

works as expected. Upon running the script I am logged in to whatever telent IP I used in the line `spawn telnet 10.21.0.17`

Then it drops me to the Shell of the AP

> WAP->

How do I issue further commands? I'd like to issue `reboot` and then maybe a `sleep 20` and finally `exit`.

I have tried using `echo` and `expect` with no success. I've also tried with removing the `interact` with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `send`, as you did for the username and password? I'm confused..

Comment: Sorry, I tried that too. I forgot to mention. `echo` `send` `expect` and `send` all do nothing. Just leaves me at the WAP--> prompt.

Comment: As seen in the resolution below, the `send` command was what was used, but the problem was I needed a `sleep` just before that first shell command. Thanks for your quick comment, though...always appreciated.

Comment: Also, `interact` would not be used because that would then wait for user interaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login#comment14621039_7789710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by simply adding a `sleep` before the `expect`, and of course [not including `interact`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login#comment14621039_7789710), the following works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 10.21.0.17
expect -re "login"
send "admin\n"
expect -re "Password"
send "supersecurepassword\n"
sleep 5
expect "WAP"
send "reboot\n"
send "exit\n"
```

For reference, this was used to automate a reboot on a D-Link DAP-2590 wireless access point. Now that I know this though, I may use it for other things: changing passwords, etc. Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Why did you need `sleep` command in this script before `expect`?