# How to telnet into Android Virtual Device (AVD) with shell script and run commands

Tags: android, bash, telnet

I would like to telnet into an AVD and change the GPS location of the AVD using a shell script.

Manually I can do `telnet localhost 5554` yielding

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'/Users/michaelcas/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
```

then I authenticate and change the GPS

```
auth BKLphG9dWG2Isxwb
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
```

and finally change location

```
geo fix -120.65962 35.28275
```

but I would like to do all the above with a Bash shell script if possible

Comment: Do you *have* to use **telnet** ? **adb shell** would be better, no ? adb push my_script_file.sh  /data/dir1/ 

adb shell sh data/dir1/my_script_file.sh

Comment: yes it would, tried it with no effect (on mac, but you're right let me try on pc)

Comment: you can use `expect`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148832/shell-script-successful-telnet-login-how-to-issue-commands-after-that