# Wait for prompt in expect script

Tags: telnet, expect, prompt

I need an `expect` script to wait for an issued command to finish, and then log out from `telnet`. Here is the script:

```
spawn telnet host
send "username\r"
send "password\r"
sleep 3
send "custom_command\r"
while {???}
{
    sleep 1
}
send "logout\r"
expect eof
```

The part that I don't know how to phrase is `???`. I basically just need to wait for the `prompt` to show up, and as soon as it shows up, the script should end. I'm guessing it should be something like `[gets line != "prompt>" ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`expect` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) of expect seems appropriate here.
Something like `expect "prompt\n"` followed by the sending of the logout.

As a note, if this is a normal telnet system you should generally wait to be prompted for username and password before just sending it over. See [how to automate telnet session using expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250564/how-to-automate-telnet-session-using-expect) or [expect script to automate telnet login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login)

Answer (score 10):

I tried the expect command, but it didn't work, after some research, trial and error I figured out the following:

1. Use `expect "prompt>\r"` instead of `expect "prompt>"`
2. Curly braces need to be on the same line as expect command, like this `expect "prompt>\r" {`
3. Use `set timeout -1` to wait for the prompt infinitely, instead of 10 seconds

So, the answer is:

```
spawn telnet host
send "username\r"
send "password\r"
sleep 3
set timeout -1
send "custom_command\r"
expect "prompt>\r" {
    send "logout\r"
    expect eof
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should really expect something before you send something, to get the timing right. Something like:

```
exp_internal 1      ;# expect internal debugging. remove when not needed
spawn telnet host
expect "login: "
send "username\r"
expect "Password: "
send "password\r"
set prompt {\$ $}   ;# this is a regular expression to match the *end* of
                     # your shell prompt. Adjust as required.
expect -re $prompt
send "custom_command\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "logout\r"
expect eof
```