# linux - telnet - script with expect

Tags: tcl, telnet, expect

I was writing an expect-script which communicate with a server via telnet, but right now i need to evaluate the reply from server.

Usage:

```
./edit.expect
```

EXPECT script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect<br>
spawn telnet ip port
expect "HUH?"
send "login testuser pass\r"
expect "good"
send "select 1\r"
expect "good"
send "me\r"
expect "nick=testuser id=ID group=testgroup login=testuser"
send "edit id=ID group=3\r"
expect "good"
send "quit\r"
```

If i send the command "me" i get a reply from the server which i need to evaluate.
The reply from server looks like this example... "nick=NICK id=ID group=GROUP login=LOGIN".

How do i extract the id of the reply and use it in a send-command?

I hope you could help me with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way too.

```
set user_id {}
expect -re {nick=(.*)\s+id=(.*)\s+group=(.*)\s+login=(.*)\n} {
        #Each submatch will be saved in the the expect_out buffer with the index of 'n,string' for the 'n'th submatch string
        puts "You have entered : $expect_out(0,string)"; #expect_out(0,string) will have the whole expect match string including the newline
        puts "Nick : $expect_out(1,string)"
        puts "ID : $expect_out(2,string)"
        puts "Group : $expect_out(3,string)"
        puts "Login : $expect_out(4,string)"
        set user_id $expect_out(2,string)
}

send "This is $user_id, reporting Sir! ;)"
#Your further 'expect' statements goes below.
```

You can customize the `regexp` as per your wish and note the use of braces `{}` with `-re` flag in the `expect` command.

If you are using braces, `Tcl` won't do any variable substitution and if you need to use variable in the `expect` then you should use double quotes and correspondingly you need to escape the backslashes and wildcard operators.

Comment: Thanks - i got it! I remember this syntax a little bit, but didn't know that expect uses TCL/Tk. ;-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

expect lets you match the incoming strings with regular expressions and get the submatches in the `expect_out()` array.  In your example, you could use

```
send "me\r"
expect -re {nick=([^ ]*) id=([^ ]*) group=([^ ]*) login=([^ ]*)}
set nick $expect_out(1,string)
set id $expect_out(2,string)
set group $expect_out(3,string)
set login $expect_out(4,string)
puts "GOT nick: $nick  id: $id  group: $group  login: $login"
send "edit id=$id group=3\r"
etc...
```

EDIT: string must be in {} to avoid command expansion

Comment: Cool, this helps me a lot, but i got this error `invalid command name "^"
    while executing
"^ "
    invoked from within
"expect -re "nick=([^ ]*) id=([^ ]*) group=([^ ]*) login=([^ ]*)""`.

Looks like, because the telnet-session says: `Escape character is '^]'.` Any ideas?

Comment: oops, serves me right for typing rather than pasting.  Inside double-quotes, [] is treated as a command expansion by tcl.