# how to run scripts within a telnet session

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

I want to connect to a remote host using telnet
there is no username/password verification
just

```
telnet remotehost
```

then I need to input some commands for initialization

and then I need to repeat the following commands:

```
cmd argument
```

argument is read from a local file, in this file there are many lines, each line is a argument
and after runing one "cmd argument", the remote host will output some results
it may output a line with string "OK"
or output many lines, one of which is with string "ERROR"
and I need to do something according to the results.

basically, the script is like:

```
initialization_cmd  #some initial comands
while read line
do    
  cmd $line
  #here the remote host will output results, how can I put the results into a variable?
  # here I want to judge the results, like
  if $results contain "OK";then
       echo $line >>good_result_log
  else
       echo $line >> bad_result_log
  fi     
done < local_file

 the good_result_log and bad_result_log are local files
```

is it possible or not? thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you add a tag for `bash` or `ksh` to improve the readership of your question. Note that the `telnet` tag has only 19 followers. Unless there are new features in bash4 that support better named-pipe-like communcation, as @cmh advises, `expect` is your best bet for this sort of problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as echo will output to the stdout of the tty and not to the stdin of the telnet process.

I would suggest writing an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script for this task. Perhaps you could adapt something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login).

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked in at least four different forums at the same time. Don't know what kind of points this kind of entrepreneurship earns, but here are links to answers:

- [linux forums](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/193839-how-run-scripts-within-telnet-session.html#post913520)
- [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/210639-how-run-scripts-within-telnet-session.html)
- [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/521716/how-to-run-scripts-within-a-telnet-session/532285#532285)