# Full backup of GoDaddy site via command-line script

Tags: mysql, shell, backup, database-backups

Is there a simple way to do an automated backup of an entire website on a host like GoDaddy via the command-line?

So far, I know I need to backup all the files in my home directory recursively. I could possibly automated SFTP to connect and issue a `get -R *` command to get the full file dump, or just use SCP.

The other half of the puzzle is getting all of the tables available, mostly WordPress tables. My guess is that maybe there's a command-line command I could issue which dumps the database contents to a flat file, which I could then also pull via SFTP. If such a command exists, my plan is to use a combination of Telnet and EXPECT scripts to login to the GoDaddy site, issue some commands, then disconnect back to my local shell.

The end result should be that I have a folder with all of my server content in it, plus the flat file backup of the SQL database from the server. I know there are WordPress backup plugins, but they tend to provide a slew of ZIP files, when all I want is the raw data directly so I can put it in my private SVN server for backup and versioning.

So my question: how do I extract all of the databases on my GoDaddy server via the command-line to a file?

Thank you.

Comment: "to a file" ?  or do a backup directory structure?

Comment: @shellter I need to dump the database to a file.

Comment: maybe a related stack exchange site can help you. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ... You might flag this and ask a moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found a working solution.

First, I used 2 separate [`expect` scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login).

1. Telnet into the server, delete old backups, use `mysqldump` to extract all tables to a flat file via `mysqldump -u db_owner -p --all-databases > output.sql`, and create a massive tarball of everything. Logout.
2. Use `SCP` to pull the newly created tarball, extract it to a local SVN controlled working copy folder.
3. Use a second `expect` script to login to the server and delete the backup. Logout.

From there, I just manually `svn add` and `svn commit` as needed.