# How to get the output of a telnet command from bash?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, telnet

I'm trying to get the list of processes running on my Windows machine from Linux, but I don't get any output when I do it in a script. If I use telnet manually and use the command pslist I get the complete list of processes, but not in my script.

Here is the bash script (minus the variables):

```
( echo open ${host}
sleep 1
echo ${user}
sleep 3
echo ${pass}
sleep 1
echo pslist
sleep 2
 ) | telnet
```

and I simply call it with `bash pslist.sh` and the output is something like that:

```
telnet> Trying ip_address...
Connected to ip_address.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service 

login: my_loginmy_passwordpslistConnection closed by foreign host.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try terminating each `echo` with \r character, like this: `echo -e "${user}\r"

Comment: echo has many portability problems, and should never be used with option flags. Consider printf instead: `printf 'name: %s\n' "$name"`. 
                http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/echo | http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq.html#Q0b | http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf

Comment: I would suggest using `expect` to script telnet.  You can learn about and download it here: http://expect.sourceforge.net/  There is an example telnet script using it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789710/expect-script-to-automate-telnet-login

Comment: @nsilent22 Thank you, that was it :) Can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @BaptisteWicht: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminate each `echo` with \r character, like this: `echo -e "${user}\r"`

Comment: For portability, `printf` is absolutely superior to `echo` with or without `-e` and with or without escape codes which are supported in some dialects but not in others.  With `printf`, all of this is properly standardized.

Answer (score 3):

`telnet` is notoriously tricky to script. You may be able to succeed more often if you add a longer still `sleep` between the commands.

A better approach is to switch to a properly scriptable client, viz. `netcat` (aka `nc`). Better still would be to install an SSH server on your Windows box (perhaps for security only make it accessible from inside your network) and set it up with passwordless authentication. Then you can simply `ssh user@ipaddress pslist`